# Overlay Text on a Centered Image Which Is Smaller Than Its Containing Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I have the following case:

1. Image which its width is less than the page width.
2. Image needs to be centered within its parent `div` (Which is wider).
3. Overlay text should be displayed on the image on one of its corners.
4. **Image can not be stretched**. Image will appear in its native size.
5. The image size can not be set in `CSS` as this template will be used for many images in different size.

So the code I came up with is given in https://jsfiddle.net/RoyiA/gdezys7j Or (Must be viewed in Full Screen so the image will be centered):

```css
@font-face {font-family: "MammaGamma";
src: url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/1d8209e6e1d626b5657d1a5b99ea9572.eot");
src: url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/1d8209e6e1d626b5657d1a5b99ea9572.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/1d8209e6e1d626b5657d1a5b99ea9572.woff2") format("woff2"),
url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/1d8209e6e1d626b5657d1a5b99ea9572.woff") format("woff"),
url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/1d8209e6e1d626b5657d1a5b99ea9572.ttf") format("truetype"),
url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/1d8209e6e1d626b5657d1a5b99ea9572.svg#MammaGamma") format("svg");
}

.image-container {
   position: relative;
   font-family: Arial;
}

.image-center{
position: relative;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.image-text-block {
   position: absolute;
display: block;
   top: 100px;
   left: 10px;
   background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
   color: white;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Image Text Blocks</h2>
<p>How to place text blocks over an image:</p>

<div class="image-container">
 <img class="image-center" src="https://i.imgur.com/0s8kLb7.png" alt="Nature">
   <div class="image-text-block">
     <h3>Created with <span style="font-family:MammaGamma; color:rgb(239, 74, 74)">Photoshop</span></h3>
     <p>Image: <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/151740882@N05/47029584231">Jane</a> by Mireille Lannoo</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem I'm having is that the text `div` is relative to the position of its parent `div` while the image is centered. How can address that?

Comment: where would you ideally want the "created by" text to appear when overlaid on the image? Centered on bottom? Or top left/right?

Comment: In the example above I aimed the text box to be on the top left. But any corner will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest wrapping the image-container block inside another div which purpose is to center it. That way the image-container block has the width of the image and your absolute positioning of the caption box should work as intended.

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.image-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image-center img {
  display: block;
}

.image-text-block {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, .5);
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Image Text Blocks</h2>
<p>How to place text blocks over an image:</p>

<div class="image-center">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0s8kLb7.png" alt="Nature">
    <div class="image-text-block">
      <h3>Created with <span style="font-family:MammaGamma; color:rgb(239, 74, 74)">Photoshop</span></h3>
      <p>Image: <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/151740882@N05/47029584231">Jane</a> by Mireille Lannoo</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the effort to assist. Actually, this is what I did when I solved it 12 hours ago: https://jsfiddle.net/RoyiA/gdezys7j/11 :-). I was waiting maybe for an elegant way around it. If nothing will come, I will mark your answer.

Comment: In your linked solution you have to set the width and height of the container div to the specific image dimensions though. With an extra wrapping div you can avoid that.

Comment: Could you please explain? I cam see indeed you don't specify the size. Is it because of the `flex`?

Comment: Correct, the 'display: flex' in combination with 'justify-content: center' will center every child element inside the 'image-center' class.

Child elements of flexboxes do not stretch to 100% width like usual block elements but are limited to their content (unless otherwise stated).
Flexboxes are really useful and unless you have to target old browser are very well supported.

This site has a good overview: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Perfect. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.image-container {
   position: relative;
   font-family: Arial;
    width:650px;
    margin: auto;
    }

.image-center{
 margin:auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-text-block {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 10px;
   background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
   color: white;
   padding:0 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Image Text Blocks</h2>
<p>How to place text blocks over an image:</p>

<div class="image-container">
 <img class="image-center" src="https://i.imgur.com/0s8kLb7.png" alt="Nature">
   <div class="image-text-block">
     <h3>Created with <span style="font-family:MammaGamma; color:rgb(239, 74, 74)">Photoshop</span></h3>
     <p>Image: <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/151740882@N05/47029584231">Jane</a> by Mireille Lannoo</p>
   </div>
</div>.
```

Your image container does not have a set width, and therefore will be the width of the screen unless you set a width. You are positioning the text to the top left corner of the container, not the image.

Comment: The problem is I want to keep the image native size. Your code stretches it to the full width of the container. As I wrote, the image is smaller than the `div` element. I want it centered and the text in one of its corners.

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of changes like so.

```
.image-center {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the will to assist. The problem is that your code stretches the image. As I wrote, I want its size to remain native.